# Get Username from NTLM token Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, iis

I used NTLM authentication at IIS server and I am using rewrite module of IIS to redirect that port to nodejs port.

Now I am getting authorization header in nodejs with NTLM token.

Now my question is,

- How can I get username in form of {domainName}{userName} from **NTLM token** in nodejs?
- Can I get groups of that user from nodejs? How?

Comment: Are you using iisnode?

Comment: no, I am using IIS to route requests to nodejs only. **I am not using IISNode**

Comment: Did you ever solve this, it's driving me nuts. I also am not using IISNode, and I already have the NTLMtoken, just need to extract the userName from it...

Comment: @Adam, You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sspi

Comment: @LaxmikantDange It doesn't work if you use IIS as a reverse proxy, because the original TCP/IP request (which NTLM/SSPI relies on) is lost when IIS forwards the HTTP traffic.

Comment: @Adam, which module you use in IIS. I think as long as the request has Authorization header, server will authenticate the request. Check if IIS is removing any headers. you can also try nginx instead of IIS.

Answer (score -1):

There are several libraries available to handle NTLM in Node, including:

[node-http-ntlm](https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-http-ntlm)
[express-ntlm](https://github.com/einfallstoll/express-ntlm)

These make it very simple to do something like:

```
httpntlm.get({
    url: "https://someurl.com",
    username: 'm$',
    password: 'stinks',
    workstation: 'choose.something',
    domain: ''
}
```

If you don't want to use one of these libraries, you will have to decode the token yourself.

You can view the source of those libbraries for help on how to do this:

https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-http-ntlm/blob/master/ntlm.js
https://github.com/einfallstoll/express-ntlm/blob/master/lib/express-ntlm.js

Comment: I dont want to authenticate user from node, Authentication process is maintained by IIS, I just want to get username from ntlm token

Comment: Then please provide more details on what you are receiving in Node. What does the header look like? Are there any body parameters?

Comment: I am getting a standard NTLM header, The header is like `Authorization: NTLM <Base64 NTLM token>`